# Calculating a complex integral by rewriting as a contour integral on |z|=1.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to show that $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{2+i\:sin\theta}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{5}}$

I used $sin\theta=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})$ and substituted $z=e^{i\theta}$. I ended up with $\int_1^1\frac{-2i\:dz}{3+z^2}$. I feel like a mental block has made me miss an otherwise obvious step or I've made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{-2i\:dz}{z^2+4z-1}$ and then use residue theorem

Comment: You won by 0.01 second ! Cheers.

Comment: But am sure that i have just lost your valuable answer@ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: I can see where I went wrong now. I failed at multiplication...

Comment: @Semsem. Are you kidding the poor and too slow old man ? Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I just remember that once your experience are over the hill, you begin to pick up speed.